# How use a makefile with Codeblocks

Tags: c++, makefile, codeblocks

I have some problems when I create and add a makefile project with Codeblocks.
I created a project which has 3 files: main.cpp; View.cpp; View.h.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "View.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    View view;
    view.box();
}
```

View.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "View.h"

using namespace std;
void View::box()
{
    int i=3;

    switch(i)
    {
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:
            break;
    }
    cout<<"AAAA";


};
```

View.h:

```
#ifndef VIEW_H_INCLUDED
#define VIEW_H_INCLUDED

class View
{
//// ****************************

//// ---------------------------


//// ---------------------------

public :

void box();


//// ****************************
};

#endif
```

And Makefile:

```
all :   lienket
lk  :   main.o View.o
    g++ main.o  View.o  -o  lienket
main.o  :   main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
View.o  :   View.cpp
    g++ -c  View.cpp
```

I ticked this is as a custom Makefile.(Project->properties->Project setting)

Finally I build but receive the following error:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in lienket (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Running command: mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile Debug
mingw32-make.exe: *** No rule to make target `Debug'.  Stop.
Process terminated with status 2 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

How do I use a makefile with Codeblocks?

Comment: `main.cpp` should `#include "View.h"`.

Comment: `mingw32-make.exe -f Makefile Debug` its trying to execute the `Debug` target which is not present in your makefile.  for a quicker fix just replace `all` in your makefile to Debug. To understand the proper solution check in the settings if `Debug` flag has to be disabled. and check if anyother settings has to be changed

Comment: sorry, i post lost , i have fix.

Comment: Post your fix in the answer section and accept it.

Comment: sorry Sagar Sakre, i dont understand your solution. my el is bad. My project is wrong where.

Answer (score 5):

When you run the build from inside `codeblock` (whatever that is), it's invoking make with the arguments `-f Makefile` (which is redundant but doesn't hurt) and `Debug`, which means that it wants to build a target named `Debug`.

But your makefile doesn't define any target named `Debug`, so you get the error you see.

Either modify your makefile and define a target named `Debug`:

```
Debug: all
```

Or else figure out how to have `codeblock` invoke make with different arguments so it doesn't have `Debug` on the command line.

Comment: your mind Debug: all
all: lienket
lk: main.o View.o
 g++ main.o View.o -o lienket
main.o: main.cpp
 g++ -c main.cpp
View.o: View.cpp
 g++ -c View.cpp

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Codeblock requires a Target Named "Debug:" in the makefile that builds your project.

The other part of the problem after setting this up corretly is getting codeblock to run the program under the debugger.  Example clicking the "red play button", not just the gear button. To set that up:

sure -g is specified to gcc or g++ in your makefile.

Use "Project->Properties-> Build targets->Output filename" to specify the name of the executable generated by your Makefile.

Use "Project->Set programs arguments" to set the command-line parameters to the program.